# Vectorise Flattend outter product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function :

```
def cross(a,b):
  shape_a = a.shape[0]
  shape_b = b.shape[0]
  cross = shape_a * shape_b
  return (np.resize(a,(shape_a,1))*np.resize(b,(1,shape_b))).flatten()
```

Is it possible to vectorise it, such that to apply it to each couple of rows of two matrices ?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use `np.resize` not `np.reshape`?

Comment: `a[:, None] * b[None, :]` is clearer than using `resize` or even `reshape`.  It makes a (shape_a, shape_b]) array.  But, wait, what the shape the 2 arrays?  1d, 2d?

Comment: what do you mean by 'each couple of rows'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many ways to do this but one quick way is to use `np.einsum` and broadcasting, reshaping the result to match your existing function:

```py
np.einsum('...i,...j', a, b).reshape((-1, a.shape[-1]*b.shape[-1]))
```

Note that einsum can be slow in certain contexts, something like `np.tensordot` may be faster.

Edit: Actually, that's way over-engineered for something like this. Just take a bit more care with your axis and your current solution works perfectly:

```py
def cross(a,b):
  shape_a = a.shape[-1]
  shape_b = b.shape[-1]
  cross = shape_a * shape_b
  return (a[..., np.newaxis]*b[..., np.neaxis, :]).reshape((-1, cross))
```

Comment: Note that his output is flattened and yours is not (I have not compared the entries themselves, or the shape fyi)

Comment: Mine is flattened on the last two dimensions, just like his. Without better specification of the problem, I can't know if he wants that (which makes more sense to me) or if he wants it completely flattened, which is trivial.

Comment: The problem with my current solution is that it is too slow for big matrices

Comment: @W.314 you never mentioned this in your question, and you don't show any existing implementation to compare timing, so it was impossible for me to know that was your problem. Regardless, this implementation should about as fast as possible without parallelisation. Give it a try: pass your entire 2D a and b matrices to the revised `cross` function.